# Android live streaming video received from a hardware via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, video-streaming, live

I have a hardware device(not a mobile/pc) that holds some videos. These videos are transferred by it via bluetooth in video format. My requirement is, I need to stream those received videos as live on my app. I am not familiar with video streaming app development. I searched alot for similar examples and not found yet. Please share if you have found one.I expect my app to work like the live tv video used in this app.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manoramaonline.mmtv&hl=en

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What have you done so far?